# How to get ID that has a maximum value of Hits by grouping Date by in LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, uipath

I have a DataTable that has the sample data like this:

```
ID | HITS | Date
1  |  12  | 1 October 2017
2  |  15  | 1 October 2017
3  |  13  | 1 October 2017
4  |   5  | 1 November 2017
5  |   7  | 1 November 2017
6  |   3  | 1 November 2017
```

The result that I want is:

```
ID   
2   ==> 15 is the max value for hits in Oct 2017 
5   ==> 7 is the max value for hits in Nov 2017
```

Prefer in VB.NET. We can do this in TSQL BUT since the data is in DataTable already so we have to manipulate at Linq level.

Any ideas?

Comment: Made a changes on the date to make it simple

Comment: You can use linq on a `DataTable.AsEnumerable` and Field(Of...) to sum, filter (WHERE) and group values.  Have you tried anything?  Those still are not dates, so they are strings?

Answer (score 2):

In order to do run this query, you need to do four things:

- Group by date
- Order each group by hit count in descending order
- Pick the first element of each group
- Take its ID

A sample in C# would look like this:

```
var res = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new {
        Id = r.Field<int>("Id")
    ,   Hits = r.Field<int>("Hits")
    ,   Date = r.Field<DateTime>("Date") // Use proper type here
    })
    .GroupBy(r => r.Date)
    .Select(g => new {
        Id = g.OrderByDescending(r => r.Hits).First().Id
    ,   Date = g.Key
    )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Any ideas do it in VB.NET?

Answer (score 0):

I see you've tagged this with UiPath. It doesn't support anonymous types, so LINQ is a big hassle, BUT, you can use the [Datatable.Select(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select(v=vs.110).aspx) method to use SQL-like syntax and query a DataTable. The syntax of DataTable.Select is the same as in [DataColumn.Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx).

I would also like to point you toward [teleriks](http://converter.telerik.com/) .Net code converter, because stackoverflow is chock full of nice .NET but it is never in VB.